# How to find all indices above a specific value in a python multidimensional list

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

I have a two dimensional list in python with some floating point values. I want to find out indices of all the elements in the list which are above a specific value.

For example, in a 2 x 4 list as below (integer for convenience):

```
100    200    100    250
125    100    250    100
```

I need the indices of all the values which are equal or above 200. These indices are [0][1], [0][3] and [1][2].

Please help in this regards.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 8):

Numpy is quite handy for this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = [[100, 200, 100, 250], [125, 100, 250, 100]]
>>> a=np.array(a)
>>> np.argwhere(a>=200)
      array([[0, 1],
             [0, 3],
             [1, 2]])
```

Answer (score 2):

You *could* do this with a nested loop:

```
indices = []
for i, row in enumerate(grid):
    for j, val in enumerate(row):
        if val > threshold:
            indices.append((i, j))
```

but it's quite likely that you should be using [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/), which offers high-speed vectorized operations and very convenient syntax. With a numpy ndarray instead of a nested list, the code is as follows:

```
numpy.where(grid > threshold)
```

Answer (score 2):

A first approch would be, without any libraries:

```
x = [ [100, 200, 100, 250],
      [125, 100, 250, 100] ]
indices = []
for i, range in enumerate(x):
    for j, elem in enumerate(range):
         if elem >= 200:
             indices.append((i, j))
```

The result is:

```
>>> indices
[(0, 1), (0, 3), (1, 2)]
```