# Search a multidimensinal list in python

Tags: python

I have the following list: `[["0", "_", "_"], ["_", "_", "_"], ["_", "_", "_"]]`.

How can i find the the index of the item that is "_".
I want it like this: [2, 0], [0, 2]...

Here's what i managed to do, but it is not working:
None: "self.matrix" is the matrix above.

```
def getAvailableMoves(self):
    availableMoves = []

    for list_ in self.matrix:
        for item in list_:
            if item == "_":
                availableMoves.append([self.matrix.index(list_), self.matrix[self.matrix.index(list_)].index(item)])

    return  availableMoves
```

Comment: I don't understand the expected output?! Right now "_" is [1,2],[0,1,2],[0,1,2].

Comment: I try to implement a minimax algorithm for a Tic Tac Toe game, so the output is the row and the column of the available move.

Comment: This seems close enough: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504898/how-to-find-all-indices-above-a-specific-value-in-a-python-multidimensional-list

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate` in your loops to get the index of the element you're on like

```
for list_ind, list_ in enumerate(self.matrix):
    for item_ind, item in enumerate(list_):
        if(item=='_'):
            availableMoves.append((list_ind,item_ind))
```